# What are Visual C++ errors with codes EXXXX?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

Sometimes, I encounter errors in Visual Studio with codes that starts with E such as E0260, E0135, etc (See the image below, for example). I couldn't find any information about them on Microsoft Docs. What tool generates them? What does the E stand for?

[image]